# Умножение матриц си++

Tags: c++, c, матрицы

Я заметил, что у меня функция пропускает последнюю строку, если матрица не квадратная при умножении. Ошибку пока не вижу, поэтому прошу помочь.

```
void multiplication(int (&a1)[4][4], int (&b)[4][4], int (&c)[4][4], int n, int l){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<l; j++){
            for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
                int save = a1[i][k]*b[k][j];
                c[i][j] += save;
                save = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Условие для умножения матриц (количество строк одной=количество столбцов второй) проверяется в другой функции.

Comment: У вас как минимум фиксировано, что первая матрица - квадратная (i от 0 до n-1, k - тоже). И, кстати, точно n и l не превышают 4? А матрица c изначально обнулена?

Comment: у меня изначально ввод размера матрицы от 2 до 4 как строк, так и столбцов

Comment: сама функция ввода не даст ввести меньше 2 и больше 4, она просто будет повторять цикл с вводом размерности

Comment: Последнюю строку это `save = 0`?

Comment: а, я не заметил даже)) записал бред, она ничего не дает)) спасибо

Comment: Хмм можете подробней описать проблему. Я скопировал вашу функцию. Передаю в нее 3 матрицы 4 на 4. Первые две заполнены случайными числами, а третья нулями. И так же передаю `n = 4` и `l = 4` и все работает и перемножает.

Comment: она работает, если две матрицы квадратные, а если одна 3 на 4, а вторая 4 на 2, то она работает не правильно

Comment: Ну а если у вас матрица 3 на 4 и 4 на 2, то как функция узнает об этом? Вы ей передаете 2 параметра всего. А тут 3, 4, 2

Comment: А, значит у меня не хватает одного цикла, верно ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe не кол-во столбцов первой == кол-во строк второй?

Comment: Ну точно, так. @Павел Ериков

Comment: Все, я исправил ошибку, я в циклах проверку сделал для квадратной матрицы и искал ошибку))) очень глупо, ну ладно. Спасибо всем, кто помогал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен новый цикл, вам нужно чтобы функция знала о всех размерах матриц, сейчас вы передаете `n` и `l` этого хватит только для умножения квадратный матриц по типу `4 на 4`.

При умножении матрицы `3 на 4` с `4 на 2` заметьте, что у вас 3 числа это `3, 4, 2`, а ваша функция на данный момент может узнать только о двух из них.

Вот правильный пример вашей функции:

```
//row1 - кол-во строк в матрице a1, col1 - кол-во столбцов в 1 
матрице, col2 - кол-во столбвоц во 2 матрице
void multiplication(int(&a1)[4][4], int(&b)[4][4], int(&c)[4][4], int row1, int col1, int col2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < col1; k++)
                c[i][j] += a1[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Для большего понимания, я переименовал переменные и подписал в комментарии, что они обозначают.

Теперь чтобы умножить матрицу `3 на 4` и `4 на 2` нужно вызывать функцию так:

```
multiplication(a, b, c, 3, 4, 2);
```

Comment: Если это правильный пример, то почему всё также есть ссылка у a1 и цифры в скобках?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков пожалуйста не надо к словам прикапывается :) это не красиво. Правильный означает, что он рабочий. А не относительно идеального кода правильный

Comment: Правильный означает, что он не только рабочий, но и не содержит ошибок.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков мдааа, ладно я не хочу продолжать этот разговор т.к. не вижу смысла. И да ссылка и цифры в скобках это не ошибка.